# Can I move a Google API implementation to a web-service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have an in-house CMS system written in ASP.NET C#, and I need to implement a few pages that can allow the user to access and alter their Google Analytics management settings using the [Google Analytics management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/).

I have added the [Google.Apis.Analytics.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3/) library from NuGet, and I managed to make it work using OAuth2 authentication.

However, the library installs several dependencies, and some of them are upgrading some of my existing DLL files. This is not good, because I have a lot of functionality in this solution and some other solutions that are based on these old DLLs.

Would it be possible to move all the Google API implementation into an external web-service and just call this from my CMS? That way, I would not have to upgrade the CMS's old references. The only problem that I've run into with this is that I have no idea how to use OAuth2 to allow the CMS user to use his own Google account since all this is now done in the web-service, and the authentication page from google will not open in the user's browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a web service will work.  The user needs to be prompted for authentication with the web browser.  You cant really do that from a web service and return the proper authentication.

The Google .net client lib uses the newest DLLs you may want to look into upgrading yours.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. It is a long and arduous task to do this, because it's a huge project, and there are also other projects in production depending on this project. So I'll have to spend 300 hours to upgrade all these systems, when I only want a page where I can see some custom definitions from Google Analytics.

Comment: Code it yourself skip the client library.   Hardest part is the authentication but you can just barrow code from the client library.